# Photo Collage in Rectangle Resizing Algorithm required?

Tags: jquery, html, css, algorithm

Firstly please see the link and then answer to the query , i have used mouse to re size the height and width instead of buttons , so i want a solution in which when i do change the height of the frame / rectangle /div the parent boundaries will remain the same as currently it will not please have a look on the link http://itsolutiontech.com/photocollage/ so please share any algorithm for it or any demo will be appreciated

Comment: sorry, i can't quite follow you: what is the parent-child relationship? what is the desired behaviour ? in general i believe that you need a data structure that contains sets of border segments that have to be shifted synchronously. define 'mousemove' handlers that perform this sync'ing. these handlers should be installed/uninstalled (or activated/deactivated) at the beginning/end of a drag operation

Comment: @collapsar have you seen the link i have pasted ?

Comment: I've even followed your link and interacted with the Page which led me to the questions and suggestions in my previous comment.

Comment: @collapsar can you suggest me how to handle the width and height or neighbours ?

Comment: i'm sorry, you haven't yet detailed the desired behaviour, so i can't.